# What does the Go compiler mean by "no such file or directory"?

Tags: go

I'm trying to compile a Go program made up of multiple modules, like so:

```
// main.go
package main
import "mst"
// do something interesting involving minimum spanning trees

// src/mst/kruskal.go
import "disjsets"
// Kruskal's algorithm follows

// src/disjsets/disjsets.go
// implements disjoint sets with union-find
```

Now, when I run either `go run main.go` or `go build` after `export GOPATH=.` in the directory containing both `main.go` and `src`, it prints

```
# disjsets
open src/disjsets/disjsets.go: No such file or directory
```

I don't get this. The file is there as `ls -l src/disjsets/disjsets.go` confirms. How can this happen? Where should the `disjsets.go` file live if Go is to find it?

(Google Go 1.0.2)

Comment: You should probably change your question topic, the compiler doesn't 'lie' so the answer to your question is there, it means "no such file or directory" Your question is not what it means by that, it's why it's saying that (if a file exists)

Comment: **Where** are you doing `export GOPATH=.`?

Comment: @jnml: in the directory containing `main.go` and `src`.

Comment: Exactly like in the joke about that lost helicopter flying around M$ headquarters :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you should read, or re-read [How to Write Go code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH)

In short:

Set you GOPATH to somewhere and export it for good. Then put some package `blah` into directory

```
$GOPATH/src/foo/bar/baz/blah # (1)
```

or

```
$GOPATH/src/blah # (2)
```

or

```
$GOPATH/src/qux/blah # (3) etc.
```

Import `blah` into other packages as

```
import "foo/bar/baz/blah" // (1)
```

or

```
import "blah" // (2)
```

or

```
import "qux/blah" // (3)
```

The package in that directory will contain the package files. Say you have only one, `blah.go`. Then its location would be

```
$GOPATH/src/foo/bar/baz/blah/blah.go // (1)

$GOPATH/src/blah/blah.go // (2)

$GOPATH/src/qux/blah/blah.go // (3)
```

If the blah package source file is named, say `proj.go` instead, then

```
$GOPATH/src/foo/bar/baz/blah/proj.go // (1)

$GOPATH/src/blah/proj.go // (2)

$GOPATH/src/qux/blah/proj.go // (3)
```

But the import paths would be the same as in the previous case.

Comment: Consider mentioning that the `export GOPATH=...` should occur in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or some such so it isn't specific to a certain shell.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this seems to solve it:

```
export GOPATH=`pwd`
```

Apparently, it needs to be an absolute path. I still find the error message very confusing, though.

Comment: I would recommend to add to your favorite shell configuration file, for example, `export GOPATH=$HOME` and then write your code for package 'foo/blah' in `~/src/foo/blah/whatever.go`. Switching GOPATH to `pwd` may make sense, but probably only in situations other than where you are now. IOW, the `pwd` hack is IMO not a good idea. Probably even more if this are someone's first steps with Go.

Comment: @jnml: I am still learning the language and the tools -- but having my code organised per language instead of per project is not how I like to work. Maybe I should change habits, I'll see.

Comment: I have all of the different language projects bellow `~/src`. The subtree path is either the public repository path (like eg.`~/src/github.com/nick/prj-in-lang-x`) and for company stuff I use eg. `~/src/gitlab.ourdomain.com/proj-in-lang-y`, which is essentially the same schema. This way all of the languages live together in peace on my disk ;-)

Comment: I also like to separate my code by language. I have a directory `~/Projects` containing subdirs `Go`, `Java`, `C++`, `Vala`, etc. I simply set my `GOPATH` env variable to `$HOME/Projects/Go` and my `Go` directory contains `src`, `pkg`, and `bin` subdirectories, as would be expected in a Go workspace. This allows me to have a fixed GOPATH and organize my code by languages without the `pwd` hack.